# using tabs to do a flash swap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have browsed all over, including these posts:

[Jquery change image on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571285/jquery-change-image-on-click)

[JQuery - how can I change an image src on click of a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322752/jquery-how-can-i-change-an-image-src-on-click-of-a-link)

http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?301972-Swap-image-on-click-Anyone

and other links as well and I guess I don't understand how it works and can't get it to work.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div style="width:475px; height:230px; background-color:#c1bfbf;">
<div style="width:450px; height:220px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; float:left;">

    <ul style="width:450px; height:220px;  list-style:none; padding:0px; border:0px; margin:0px; position:relative; float:left;">
        <li id="first" style="padding:0px; border:0px; margin:0px;"><img src="images/imagegraph2.png" /></li>
        <li id="second" style="padding:0px; border:0px; margin:0px;"><img src="images/imagegraph1.png" /></li>

    </ul>
</div>
    <div style="width:25px; height:110px; position:relative; float:left;">
        <a href="#first"><img src="images/2nd.png" /></a>
    </div>

    <div style="width:25px; height:110px; position:relative; float:left;">
        <a href="#second"><img src="images/1st.png" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code works using anchor tags, but the problem is it pulls the page down to the anchor which I don't want. So I moved on to jQuery and image swaps. I've implementing other peoples codes to see if they work and I can't get them to work. I've used this jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.menulink').click(function () {
        $("#bg").attr('src', "images/imagegraph1.png");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Matched up with this HTML:

```
<a href="#" title="Switch" class="menulink">switch me</a>
<img src="images/imagegraph2.png" id="bg" />
```

And all that happens is the showing of imagegraph2.png and not the switching of imagegraph1.png. Usually when you do  and then hit the "=" sign, a list of possible links comes up for your image. When its in Javascript, it doesn't do that, you just put what folder/name of file. So I'm sure I'll get some negative votes here, but I have exhausted all avenue's to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `e.preventDefault();`

```
$(function () {
    $('.menulink').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#bg").attr('src', "images/imagegraph1.png");
    });
});
```

Comment: doesn't work, the image still just sits there with no switch using just the javascript: $(function () {
    $('.menulink').click(function () {
        $("#bg").attr('src', "images/imagegraph1.png");
        return false;
    });
}); and the only html on the page: <a href="#" title="Switch" class="menulink">switch me</a>
<img src="images/imagegraph2.png" id="bg" />

Comment: Open the Developer tools console and check for any errors.. Are you including jQuery script file in the first place ?

Comment: yes it is in a separate file so it looks like this: <!doctype html>
<html class=" js csstransforms3d" lang="en">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function () {
        $('.menulink').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#bg").attr('src', "images/imagegraph1.png");
        });
    });

</script>

Comment: Try giving the `MIME` type of javascript files.. Some browsers might not recognize without a proper mime type  `type="application/javascript"`  .. Do you see any errors in the console ??

Comment: Try running it on a browser

Comment: oh I do, I view it in FireFox and IE, but to no avail

Comment: Your script looks fine to me .. Try this `<script type="application/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.menulink').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#bg").attr('src', "images/imagegraph1.png");
        });
    });
</script>`